# how can i dynamically add a div to my page after the body tag?

Tags: javascript

i wrote the following code, only problem it places the div before the closing  tag 
and i want it to be at the beginning.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

        window.onload = function createDiv1() {
            var divTag1 = document.createElement("div");

            divTag1.id = "mid section";

            divTag1.setAttribute("align", "center");

            divTag1.className = "dynamicDivmid";

            divTag1.innerHTML = "pp";
            document.body.appendChild(divTag1);


        }
```

Comment: "after the body tag"? If I don't read the content I thought you want a `<div>` outside the `<body>` tag!

Answer (score 7):

Try like this:

```
document.body.insertBefore(divTag1, document.body.firstChild)
```